# How to fix an ImageView to the bottom of a Layout?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-linearlayout, android-framelayout

I have a FrameLayout with a vertical LinearLayout inside. I have an ImageView that I want to sit at the very bottom of my layout. I'm not sure how to do this. I added it as the last element in my LinearLayout but it's not fixed to the bottom. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please post your layout code.  I highly recommend not using RelativeLayout, for a number of reasons.  usually there is some other component of your view that you'd like to take up the rest of the space, and if you give that layout_weight, as mentioned in another answer, that will solve your problem.

As an example, this will always put what you want at the bottom:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        <!-- fills the area -->
    </ListView>


    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageNew"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What reasons for not using RelativeLayout are you talking about .. just out of curiosity.

Comment: RelativeLayout is one of those things that seems simple but is very complicated.  I think you really need to spend a few good hours tweaking the different possible settings to really understand it.  In ALMOST all cases that I've seen, where somebody used a RelativeLayout, they could have used LinearLayout and saved a whole lot of hassle.  This example is a classic.  One part of the layout is fixed (top or bottom), something else should stretch to fill.  Very easy with LinearLayout.  Very hard with RelativeLayout.  I do Android day in/day out, and almost never use Relative.

Comment: I guess I am over the learning hump. I do Android every day too and find RelativeLayout very handy sometimes.. so apart from understanding it there is no disadvantage I assume. Although it might be a bit less performant.. might..

Comment: I'm amending my position.  I find the learning curve steep and complex situations tend to be weird.  I've also taken over code from other devs, and there seems to be this urge to use RelativeLayout with people who are new, like its a sign that they're "sophisticated".  Generally, it ends bad.  Performance *should* be better with RelativeLayout, but I think that's a minor benefit when weighed to the complexity, and with newer phones, not sure you could ever notice. Expert devs, Relative is OK. Most devs, dangerous. Very sharp knife. Will cut.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Comment: I tried that with no luck :(. Also tried `android:baselineAlignBottom="true"`

Comment: @SheehanAlam OK try using `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`

Comment: Should I put the imageView in a RelativeLayout and set the parentBottom to true? I did that, but no difference..

Comment: More often than not, in my experience, you wind up making things really complex with RelativeLayout.  Linear is a lot easier.  Usually.  NOT always, but like 95% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a LinearLayout?? You could just use a RelativeLayout and do what Eng Fouad said. But, if you *really* want to use a LinearLayout, you can use android:layout_weight to make the rest of the views take up the leftover space so your last view is forced to the bottom. Maybe even add a dummy view that simply takes up all the space before the last view and shows an empty background or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a Relativelayout.

```
<ImageView 
      ......
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
```